# git push without setting upstream

Tags: git, version-control

If creating a branch off master branch by:

```
git checkout -b general
```

then I can push branch general just by:

```
git push
```

If running

```
git branch -vv
```

I can see `general` is not tracking any remote branch. So, how can I push without having set any upstream?

Comment: Can you show the output of `git push`?

Comment: On git push it should throw you an error and suggestion. This is what I got when I ran those same commands `git push --set-upstream origin general`. What version of Git are you using?

Comment: It's possible you have either an alias, or some other configuration, defined that is over-riding the default behaviour. Check `git config --list` for anything that might be relevant.

Comment: Also, do `git ls-remote origin` (or whatever your remote name is) and show the output of this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how can I push without having set any upstream?

The `git push` command only requires that you have an upstream set when using:

- a `push.default` that is set to

  - `simple` or
  - `upstream`

Note that there are five possible settings (see [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)): `none`, `current`, `matching`, `simple`, and `upstream`.  While `none` will fail, it won't fail *because of the lack of an upstream:* it fails because it just always fails.  The `current` and `matching` settings do not use the upstream of the current branch, and in fact, `matching` does not even require that there *be* a current branch.

The *first* bullet point (less indented) here is meant to indicate that you must be doing a `git push` that uses the `push.default` setting in the first place.  Note that:

`git push remote refspec`

never even reaches the first bullet point, because you supplied a *refspec* argument to `git push`.  (See [the `git push` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).)

So, that gives you the answers to your question: either specify a refspec during your `git push`, or set `push.default` to some value such that your lack of a refspec invokes the `push.default` that you have set that does not require an upstream.

Comment: That's it! Have `push.default=current` in my git configuration. Thank you

Comment: However, I have one more question. If I have two or more `remote` which one is being chosen? In my case is `origin` but what defines that choice?

Comment: If you run `git push <remote>`, that sets the remote; if you run `git push` without a remote, Git will use the remote from the current upstream, or `origin` if all else fails.

Comment: How the current upstream is being defined/changed?

Comment: The upstream setting of the current branch B is from two `git config` entries: branch.B.remote and branch.B.merge. One supplies the name of the remote. I'd have to check the source to be sure, but I suspect that if `git push` is looking for a remote to pick, it doesn't use the full parser but rather just picks out the one `branch.whatever.remote` setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup your branch to track a remote branch , you could use

> **git checkout -b <branch> <remote>/<branch>**

Below will create a local copy of your branch , but would not set a remote branch to which it should track to.

> git checkout -b general